# I can't uninstall open office 4.1.7

Tags: uninstall, openoffice

I just got a brand new laptop. I install open office but could not make it run. So I try to uninstall it. But I can't do that either. :(

When I try using the Windows remove program option from the control panel I get the Following message (French is my native language please bear with me):

Veuillez quitter OpenOffice 4.1.7 et le démarrage rapide de OpenOffice 4.1.7 avant de continuer. Si vous utilisez un système multi-utilisateur, assurrez-vous également qu'aucun autre utilisateur n'a ouvert OpenOffice 4.1.7.

Which translate to (Something like):
Exit OpenOffice 4.1.7 and OpenOffice 4.1.7 quick lunch before continuing. If you have more user make sure no other user have open OpenOffice 4.1.7.

I try restarting the laptop (twice) and it did not help.

When i try using the Modify button I end up with OpenOffice wizard. I try to uninstall it from their to no avail. I am told that some file need to be updated so i need to close the Following program: OpenOffice 4.1.7 (Process Id: 7132)

So I went to my command promt and type in: Taskkill \PID 7132 \F

To which I got (translation again or take a look at the [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgXrI.png)):

Error: process PID 7132 could not be stop

Reason: no running instance of this task exist (end translation)

I have no idea what else to try.

PS.:Sorry for any broken english in this post, I am a fulltime french speaker

Comment: Go to Start, Settings, Apps and remove Microsoft Office there. New computers include Office and that is likely what is stopping Open Office

Comment: thank for the tip, i need to reinstall open office and I will try that

Answer (score 0):

Ok took a short break, and then notice the ignore button. I hit it en open office got remove.

Thank you all for your time.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/931185)

Comment: @Ramhound Given that the OP self answered I'd say it was an answer?

Comment: @DavidPostill - I could not tell due to the massive amounts of grammatical mistakes honestly.